# Variable name must begin with a letter on .cshrc

Tags: linux, freebsd

I'd like to adjust .cshrc as below:

```
# $FreeBSD: src/share/skel/dot.cshrc,v 1.14.6.1 2008/11/25 02:59:29 kensmith Exp $
#
# .cshrc - csh resource script, read at beginning of execution by each shell
#
# see also csh(1), environ(7).
#

alias h     history 25
alias j     jobs -l
alias la    ls -a
alias lf    ls -FA
alias ll    ls -lA

# A righteous umask
umask 22

set path = (/sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin $HOME/bin)



setenv  EDITOR  vi
setenv  PAGER   more
setenv  BLOCKSIZE   K
setenv  PKG_DBDIR   ~/db/pkg

if ($?prompt) then
    # An interactive shell -- set some stuff up
    set filec
    set history = 100
    set savehist = 100
    set mail = (/var/mail/$USER)
    if ( $?tcsh ) then
        bindkey "^W" backward-delete-word
        bindkey -k up history-search-backward
        bindkey -k down history-search-forward
    endif
endif
set path = ($path $HOME/local/python/bin)
```

But the error is occurred when I do `source .shrc`

Comment: You do know that all sane users abandoned Csh 30+ years ago?

Comment: I was able to `source` what you posted without error using `tcsh` v6.18.  Is there anything additional in the error about where in that file the error may be coming from?  If you could clarify which implementation of the C shell you are using (`csh` or `tcsh` or something else) and which version you are using, someone may be able to find what the issue could be.  I was only able to replicate your error by using the wrong syntax for one of the `set` lines, but as posted it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Thanaks you guys reply to me. But I was hurry, I have asked the VPS company to refresh my space. I will reffer here, when I stragle with the same issue.

Comment: You have not shown the error.

Comment: The title of your question and the comments in the displayed file indicate it's `.cshrc`, but the command you said returns an error is for the file `.shrc`.  Is there a broken file named `.shrc` that's producing the error instead of the good `.cshrc` file?

Comment: @tripleee Unfortunately I still see installation and other scripts written in `csh` by major vendors. Examples include Gaussian (computational chemistry) and bioinformatics packages (gene sequencing, x-ray crystallography, and others). The is also one person in my agency that writes in `ksh` which might be forgivable.

Comment: Having scripts written in Csh is weird and vaguely scary, but does not compel you to use it as your interactive shell.